# How to start countdown after get time from database?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need start countdown after get time from database.

For example:
You've booked a hotel reservation, and after 20 minutes you pay for it.

Where is my problem?

Database:

`updated_at = 2016-10-11 11:47:58`

HTML(framework is laravel 5):

```
<input type="hidden" id="updated_at" value="{{ $reserve -> updated_at }}">
<div>Reservation closes in <span id="time"></span> minutes!</div>
```

script:

```
function startTimer(duration, display) {
    var updated_at = $('#updated_at').val();
    console.log(updated_at);
    var start = Date.now(updated_at),
            diff,
            minutes,
            seconds;
    function timer() {
        diff = duration - (((Date.now(updated_at) - start) / 1000) | 0);

        minutes = (diff / 60) | 0;
        seconds = (diff % 60) | 0;

        minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
        seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

        display.textContent = minutes + ":" + seconds;

        if (diff <= 0) {
            start = Date.now(updated_at) + 1000;
        }
    };
    timer();
    setInterval(timer, 1000);
}

window.onload = function () {
    var fiveMinutes = 60 * 20,
            display = document.querySelector('#time');
    startTimer(fiveMinutes, display);
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's fine, except your code to display it is wrong. "display" is not defined in the `timer` function, only in the `onload` function, and it's not global so that context doesn't carry across. You probably had an error in your browser console, although you didn't mention it. To solve:

1) Change

```
var fiveMinutes = 60 * 20,
display = document.querySelector('#time');
```

to simply

```
    var fiveMinutes = 60 * 20;
```

2) Change

```
display.textContent = minutes + ":" + seconds;
```

to

```
$("#time").text(minutes + ":" + seconds);
```

3) Change

```
startTimer(fiveMinutes, display);
```

to

```
startTimer(fiveMinutes);
```

4) Change

```
function startTimer(duration, display) {
```

to

```
function startTimer(duration) {
```

And that's all.

Comment: Thank you so much, but not work this code! please check this site:
https://jsfiddle.net/45uLjk1g/1/

Comment: 1) you have a syntax error elsewhere: `var fiveMinutes = 60 * 20,` should be `var fiveMinutes = 60 * 20;`. 2) you didn't include jquery in the fiddle. 3)  I forgot that `display` was being passed to the timer function, so that needs removing. See it working here: https://jsfiddle.net/45uLjk1g/4/ . I have updated the answer to include all the complete steps required.

Comment: No, this time is: 2016-10-11 11:47:58 , and this time 20 minute grace period to pay. after 20 min this reserve expire.

Comment: ?? Not sure how this info is relevant. I've shown you how to get it working and showing the countdown from 20 to 0. What's the issue?

Comment: Thank you so much, I find my problem :-)